# SSH - Connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, vmware-esxi, oracle

I have setup on a server VMware ESXi 5.5.0. I have add the operating system Oracle Linux 5

I'm trying to setup ssh for local computers that runs on Ubuntu. But I get the error Connection refused.

I checked if the port is open on the server with "nmap 10.0.1.26" and I get the ouput

```
PORT   | STATE  | SERVICE 
22/tcp | closed | ssh
```

I also wasn't able to find the file "known_hosts"

Thank you

Comment: Did you activate and start the SSH server? What does `chkconfig  --list sshd` and `service sshd status` say?

Comment: Does not recognise the command service and chkconfig.

Comment: I have started the SSH server, but what do you mena activate?

Comment: On the server, `sudo netstat -tlnp` will let you know if there is a process listening on port 22 (and any other ports), which will partly answer @SvW's questions. The command `iptables -L -nv` on the server may also help if ssh is running and listening on port 22.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I'm oversimplifying, but did you check if sshd is running on server 10.0.1.26?

```
$ /sbin/service sshd status
```

see:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/gksja.html#gksrd

Comment: Yeap I checked and I get the output: openssh-daemon (pid 3968) is running...

Comment: Does ssh FROM your server works? Did you check firewall/iptables issues? (`iptables --list`)
Also: check `/var/log/secure` on your server for error messages

Comment: This must be iptables. Run the following and check if it works:
$ iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
$ iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$ iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$ iptables -F

if this doesn't help, try to check if sshd is defined in /etc/hosts.deny

Comment: I have disabled the firewall, but nothing changed

Comment: If `sshd` is running, it's not listening on 10.0.1.26 port 22. You should check `sshd_config` to see what address and port it's configured to listen on, and then maybe `netstat` to see whether something is actually listening on port 22.